# Which is correct, only ours or ours only?

Tags: adverb-placement

There's a sentence :

> I feel like this place is ours.

but the speaker actually felt the place was "only" for them, so I want to include the word in the sentence but don't know where to put it. (The place wasn't actually made for them, but he felt like it since there was no one else.)

> (I) Feel like this place is **only ours.**
>
> (I) Feel like this place is **ours only.**

Then which one is correct?
I've googled it and I found both "only ours" and "ours only" are used, so I'm not sure which one I should use. I already saw [this one](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/adjectives/only), but I'm still confused.

Or is it better to just say "this place is **only for us**"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first one sounds more natural but the second could be used if you want to put extra special emphasis on "only."

The second one sounds a bit odd, actually.  A more common expression with that same emphasis would be

> I feel like this place is ours alone.

or

> I feel like this place is ours and ours alone.

Comment: So "alone" and "only" means the same? "alone" instead of "only" is generally used in the end of the sentence in English?

Comment: "Alone" isn't generally a synonym for "only," but it is when referring to a person.  "Ours and ours alone" is a common saying in English.  I may also say "I, alone, know the answer to the question" or "you, and you alone, are responsible for your actions."  Also, "I gave my heart to you alone."  All very dramatic in their emphasis.